# apache redirect based on cookies content

Tags: angularjs, mod-rewrite, cookies, apache2.4

I have a cookies content name let's say user which has cookie value of student and teacher. Now what I have to do is when user visits site and is already logged I have to redirect him to /student page if user is student and to /teacher page if user is teacher.Here how I tried

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$ 
<If " %{HTTP_COOKIE} != 'student'">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /student?%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
</If>
<Else>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* /teacher.html?%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
```

But it shows error message of configuration misconfigured with status error code of 500.
I tried this as well

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} .*client-id.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !cookie=student
RewriteRule ^ /student.html?%{HTTP_HOST} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} .*client-id.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !cookie=teacher
RewriteRule ^ /teacher?%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
```

client id is cookie for client( both student and teacher)
But this redirect me only to /student page only even if user is teacher.

Answer (score 0):

If and Else directives are available for use since apache 2.4. I think you are using a lower version so you are getting a 500 error. You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^user=(student|user)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect **/anyuri/**  to **/teacher** if the cookie value is Teacher or **/student** if the value is Student .

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: it gives  www.localhost.com redirected you too many times. I did clear cookies but it still same